# PHP preg_match not working as Input pattern

Tags: php, html, regex, input, preg-match

So I have this input pattern in HTML:

`<input name="firstnamereg" type="text" pattern="[/\p{L}+/u ]+">`

But When I use the preg_match it does not work:

`$regexFirstANDLastname = "/[/\p{L}+/u ]+/";`

`preg_match($regexFirstANDLastname, $_POST["firstnamereg"]);`

Comment: Might need to escape your regex within php a bit better. Try this `[\/\p{L}+\/u ]+`

Comment: This is a wrong syntax, you must have wanted `pattern="[\p{L}\s]+"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
pattern="[\p{L}\s]+"
```

This pattern, in Chrome and Firefox, will be compiles as a `new RegExp("^(?:[\\p{L}\\s]+)$", "u")` regex object. The `u` flag is used by default, you do not need to pass the flag in a regex literal construct. The `pattern` regex is always set with a string, not a regex literal.